# How to integrate Zeppelin Solr

Tags: apache-zeppelin

After create Solr interpreter then trying to query collection through zookeeper, however it is throwing Exception Caused by: org.noggit.JSONParser$ParseException:

Comment: Can you show some code or configuration related to this error?

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to look at this directly? you can go via the jdbc service it wasn't too complicated

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/solr-jdbc-apache-zeppelin.html